# Swift UIKit Combine - How to reload tableview when handling publisher events?

Tags: swift, mvvm, uikit, tableview, combine

Using Combine and UIKit, I am trying to update my tableview when the array contained in the viewModel changes. My tableview's datasource is separate because I would like to reuse the file (Different objects all have a name var, so the tableviews will display a list of names).

The viewModel:

```
class ViewModel {
  @Published var items = [ItemViewModel]()
  let service = NetworkService()

  init() {
    fetchItems()
  }
    
  func fetchItems() {
    service.fetchItems { items in {
    self.items = items.map { ItemViewModel($0) }
  }
}
```

The datasource:

```
class GenericDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
   var list = [String]()

   func setList(_ list: [String]) {
       self.list = list
   }

  // then the usual tableView datasource boilerplate
}
```

The viewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let viewModel = ViewModel()
  let tableDataSouce = GenericDataSource()
  var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  func setupBinding() {
    // I want to: 1) map over viewModel.$items to get [item.name]
    //            2) assign the list of names to tableDataSource.list
    //            3) reload the tableview so the new values are displayed
  }
```

I'm not sure what Combine functions to use. My current (working) code is as follows:

```
func setupBinding() {
     viewModel.$items.handleEvents(receiveOutput: { [weak self] items in
         self?.dataSource.setList(items.map { $0.name })
         
            // dispatch called because I get yelled at for not being on main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                 self?.itemsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
           .sink { _ in }
           .store(in: &subscriptions)
 }
```

It works, but I feel like I'm brute forcing it. Is there a cleaner way to perform the binding with the current setup?

Is there a cleaner way to setup the code so the binding will be easier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Cleaner" is subjective, but a more "Combine-y" way would be:

```
viewModel.$items
   .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
   .sink { [weak self] items in
      self?.dataSource.setList(items.map(\.name))
      self?.itemsTableView.reloadData()
   }
   .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

You could also use a `.map` operator to get the array of names:

```
.map { $0.map(\.name) }
// ...
.sink { [weak self] names in
// ...
}
```

but that's a matter of taste, I think.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, when I wrote cleaner I think what I meant was "Combine-y" haha. I appreciate the help